# Empty data attributes cause jQuery bugs

Tags: jquery

I have a link like this:

```
<a id="btn_useIt" data-KDX_Main_Title="'.$fetch['KDX_Title'].'"> Link </a>
```

The `$fetch['KDX_Title']` comes from my SQL query but sometimes this value is empty.

I've this JS line allowing me to populate a text box with the value:

```
$("#btn_useIt").click(function(){
  $('#KDX_Main_Name').val($(this).attr("data-KDX_Main_Name"));
});

<input type="text" name="KDX_Main_Name" id="KDX_Main_Name">
```

The problem is:
If the value is `empty`, it does not work. My text box is not populate.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Define "does not work"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#btn_useIt").click(function(){
  $('#KDX_Main_Name').val($(this).data("KDX_Main_Name"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get `data-*` attributes.

```
$("#btn_useIt").click(function(){
  $('#KDX_Main_Name').val($(this).data("KDX_Main_Name"));
});
```

As you said when value is empty, it doesn't work, but i'm sure it will be working because when  value is blank then it will also set blank value to `input` how can you determine then??

You have to define **What doesn't work**!

Comment: If it's empty the data attribute is like that: data-kdx_main_name.